# When i use double it shows my number as 1.0E7?

Tags: java

```
class Moqueet {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        double a, b, c;
        a = 1;
        b = 10000000;
        c = a * b;
        System.out.println(c);
    }
    }
    when i use double it shows output as 1.0E7
```

But when i use integer its 10000000.

Is there any way by which i can force double to show my number as 10000000.0 instead of 1.0E7

Answer (score 3):

If you can't get used to the very sensible default format for a floating point double stringification, then use `printf` and supply an appropriate *format specifier*, `%f` is good for this case:

`System.out.printf("%f\n", c);`

`\n` is used for the newline.

Comment: I used System.out.printf("%f\n", c); but now output is 10000000.000000 is there any way to get rid of so many zero after decimal ?

Comment: @Abdul.Moqueet `%.1f` to specify one decimal.

Comment: Used %1f still the same :/

Comment: Did you forget the `.`? It is `%.1f`.

Comment: System.out.printf("%.1f\n", c); .
Please use this one, and if the answer works do vote the comment :)

Comment: @dildeepak: would you answer comprehensively if we reopend the question? To me the duplicate is not quite right, this question seems to be more about "how can I format a double with a specific format".

Comment: @Bathsheba, I understand the concern, but i just tried to provide the precise answer what developer was looking into. Thanks.